# images not showing in HTML, error 404 but path is correct

Tags: html

My images are not showing up in my website and I don't know why. When I click on the path link in my IDE, it brings me to the right images so I know the path is correct. I tried putting `../` before the path since the images were in a different directory than the html file but I'm still getting a 404 error.

I have the following set up in my project folder:

[image]

At first, my CSS file wasn't found either until I added the `../` so I tried that with the images and still nothing.

HTML:

```html
<section>
    <!-- All image layers -->
    <img src="../images/vacation/ColoredBackground.png" id="bg">
    <img src="../images/vacation/BackMountain.png" id="BackMountain">
    <img src="../images/vacation/BackTrees.png" id="BackTrees">
    <img src="../images/vacation/FrontMountains.png" id="FrontMountains">
    <img src="../images/vacation/FrontTrees.png" id="FrontTrees">
    <img src="../images/vacation/GreenMountain.png" id="GreenMountain">
    <img src="../images/vacation/RightPlants.png" id="RightPlants">
    <img src="../images/vacation/LeftPlants.png" id="LeftPlants">
    <img src="../images/vacation/Car.png" id="Car">
    <img src="../images/vacation/Clouds.png" id="Clouds">
    <img src="../images/vacation/Road.png" id="Road">
</section>
```

Terminal:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/ColoredBackground.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/BackMountain.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/FrontMountains.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/FrontTrees.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/GreenMountain.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/BackTrees.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/RightPlants.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/Clouds.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/LeftPlants.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/Car.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2021 13:26:13] "GET /images/vacation/Road.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: do you locate your images with IDE autocomplete?

Comment: @callmenikk No, typed them manually.

Comment: what about to use autocomplete? sometimes IDE can't recognize manualy typed

Answer (score 1):

Put the images folder in static folder.
Then write {`{%static 'images/vacation/img_name'%}`}
Django just load static files like images, js, css and other static stuff from static folder.
Try this it would help most probably.

Comment: It didn't work with `{% static 'images/vacation/img_name' %}` but I put my images folder in static as you suggested and just edited the path name to `../static/images/vacation/img_name`. The images now show but I'm getting an error 304...

Comment: Are you using Django or any other framework?

Comment: I'm using Flask